# How to obtain this equation of hyperspectral image restoration using total variation in the following equation?

Tags: matrix-decomposition, image-processing, dimensional-analysis, total-variation

While reading the paper "Total-Variation-Regularized Low-Rank Matrix
Factorization for Hyperspectral Image Restoration" I came through the following equation. Can someone help me how the last equation 26 is coming out of this? Thanks in advance.
[image]